# Python y NodeJs (que hacer si el cliente no tiene python)

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, nodejs, npm

Estoy intentando hacer una aplicación de escritorio con NodeJs (electron) y quiero poder implementar también scripts de python usando **Child Process** en Node, pero me gustaría saber que puedo hacer para controlar cuando un usuario no tenga Python instalado en su maquina.
¿Alguna forma de instalarle python al cliente sin necesidad de que tenga que hacerlo manual, o si tiene una versión distinta instalada no tenga conflictos; o de compilar el .py para que no sea necesario Python?

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const ls = spawn("python", ["fileController.py"]);

ls.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on("close", (code) => {
console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

*Si existe otra forma, con estas características, aunque no sea con child process, estoy abierto a sugerencias.*

Comment: Haz un comando que pida la version de python antes de iniciar el programa, si no cuenta con una version mayor, o simplemente devuelve error... Sal del programa y muestrale un mensaje: "Es necesario python para correr esta aplicacion"

Comment: La verdad es incuherente de que asignes script de pyton a un equipo de un usuario al cual si lo vemos de manera organizacional, no tendria privilegios de instalar software de terceros el cual es un punto de seguiridad debes de reformular nuevamente tu base si realmente es optimo lo que estas desarrollando en este momento.

Comment: Si es Windows, puedes incluir los binarios de Python en el instalador de la aplicación con los [paquetes embembibles](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

Comment: @aeportugal ¿Alguna documentación o tutorial de como implementarlo?

Comment: En el sitio oficial de Python puedes descargar la versión portable del interprete llamada "Windows embeddable package", de esta manera lo puedes incluir al interno de tu app como una dependencia y el cliente no tiene que instalarlo.